# How to create or send a message after receiving a self message?

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, inet

I have been trying to create and send a control packet (reply)  at a certain calculated time after processing the received request and i have a problem regarding to the code.

Here is a part of my code:

```
CBFREP *GPSR::createREP (CBFREQ *req)
{    
     CBFREP *repPkt = new CBFREP("CBFREP");
     repPkt->setPktType(REP);
     repPkt->setCreatorAdd(req->getCreatorAdd());
     ...........
      ........
     return repPkt;
}

void GPSR::processSelfMessage(cMessage *message)
{

    if (message == contentionTimer)
          CBFREP *rep = createREP(req);
```

The code error is :
**undeclared identifier "req".**

I am using instant veins-4.7.1

Comment: in the last line in your code, you passed **req** as a parameter, but i don't see where you declared it, maybe the problem is here, or maybe you need to provide more code enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: `req` is local name for the parameter passed to `createREP`, and does not exist in `processSelfMessage`.  You need to pass a pointer to some other `CBFREQ` object.

Comment: Undeclared Identifier errors pop up when you don't declare something (variables/functions). In your code you haven't declared 'req' inside GPSR function.